# NSPredicate filtering through dictionary and keeping keys

Tags: ios, swift

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
let array = (Array(MyVariables.dictionary.values) as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
self.searchArray = array as! [String]
```

I want to somehow attach the dictionary keys to the filtered dictionary values?  My code above creates a new array with just the filtered values but not the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the use of `NSPredicate` and try to use the `filter` function, lets say you have a dictionary of `[String:String]` declared like in the following sample:

```
let dict = ["key1": "a", "key2": "ab", "key3": "ac", "hello": "d"]
```

Then you can just use the `filter` function like in the following way with short closure syntax:

```
// the $0.1 mean the value of the dictionary, if you want to refer to the key you need to use $0.0 instead
var result = dict.filter { $0.1.containsString("a") }
```

Or just in more large way but more understandable in some ways:

```
var result = dict.filter { (key, value) -> Bool in
    return value.containsString("a")
}
```

and the above two code returns an array with the keys and values of the dictionary:

```
[("key1", "a"), ("key2", "ab"), ("key3", "ac")]
```

Just you need to adapt the above code with your `searchController.searchBar.text!` and the other things you need.

I hope this help you.

Comment: looks good the data gets properly stored into result, however im having trouble extracting the data from result?  I tried result.values and it wouldnt work so I tried making result a type dictionary and then it broke the filter

Comment: @SlopTonio Remember that `result` is an array, you can iterate over it with a `for` statement just like this : `for value in result { print(value.0) print(value.1) }`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `filter` function instead of an `NSPredicate`.  My Swift is extremely rusty, but try something like the following (warning: syntax errors may ensue):

```
self.searchArray = MyVariables.dictionary.filter() {
    (var key, value) in
    return value.contains(searchController.searchBar.text)
}
```